# Default Rails Path to Environment Log File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I'm creating a rotating logger for my staging and production environment. So I've written the following code:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(config.log_path, 2 , 'daily')
```

Now my question is how do you get the log_path, can you dynamically link it depending on the current env? My logs are located in log/ (default path I think) and the file is staging.log / production.log depending on te env.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this quick fix solution:

```
Rails.root.join('log',"#{Rails.env}.log")
```

Wondering if there's a better one.